# For loop continuing past set end point (matlab)

Tags: matlab, for-loop, variable-length

I have an array of matrices which are all different lengths. I want to compare the distance of each item in matrix 1 to the items in matrix 2 and so on. The for loops I've written below work well except when it reaches a matrix which is length 2. The loop continues to xx = 3 and then calls an error ("Index in position 1 exceeds array bounds. Index must not exceed 2.") because there is no current_mat(3,:). Why is it doing this only for matrices of length 2? I'm relatively new to matlab, so apologies if this is a simple question. Here are some toy data that give the same error I am seeing with a larger dataset.

```
matrix_1 = ones(16,3)
matrix_2 = ones(14,3)
matrix_3 = ones(2,3)
matrix_4 = ones(10,3)
my_array = {matrix_1; matrix_2; matrix_3; matrix_4}

for ii = 1:length(my_array)-1;
    current_mat = my_array{ii};
    compare_mat = my_array{ii+1};
    for xx = 1:length(current_mat);
        xx_info = current_mat(xx,:);
    end
end
```

Comment: I would recommend that you never, ever use `length`. It is useless. `numel` is faster for vectors, or be explicit about which size you want with matrices: `size(…, dim)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that when given a matrix input `length` returns the *longest* dimension of the matrix, not the number of rows. In the case of your `matrix_3` this is 3 although it appears that you expect 2. So `xx` goes from 1 to 3 and in line 11 you attempt to access a row that doesn't exist when `xx=3`. Better would be to explicitly loop across the `m` dimension. You can do this with `size` which returns the number of rows and columns in the matrix:

```
matrix_1 = ones(16,3)
matrix_2 = ones(14,3)
matrix_3 = ones(2,3)
matrix_4 = ones(10,3)
my_array = {matrix_1; matrix_2; matrix_3; matrix_4}

for ii = 1:length(my_array)-1;
    current_mat = my_array{ii};
    compare_mat = my_array{ii+1};
    [m,n] = size(current_mat); % <-- use size here, not length
    for xx = 1:m;
        xx_info = current_mat(xx,:);
    end
end
```

or, if you wish to look at the columns:

```
matrix_1 = ones(16,3)
matrix_2 = ones(14,3)
matrix_3 = ones(2,3)
matrix_4 = ones(10,3)
my_array = {matrix_1; matrix_2; matrix_3; matrix_4}

for ii = 1:length(my_array)-1;
    current_mat = my_array{ii};
    compare_mat = my_array{ii+1};
    [m,n] = size(current_mat); % <-- use size here, not length
    for xx = 1:n;
        xx_info = current_mat(:,xx);
    end
end
```

Comment: i realize that OP's internal FOR loop doesn't really do a comparison, but if you compare across rows, it will still give an error, won't it?. Shouldn't OP be comparing across columns which will be consistent in this case?

Comment: I wouldn't presume to read into that. I don't know what the OP wishes to compare. I updated the answer to show both ways.

Comment: This explains the problem nicely, but fixes it with awkward syntax. OP needs to replace `length(current_mat)` with `size(current_mat,1)`. There is no need to extract two values if one only needs one of them.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work for you. You didn't specifically specify the length of columns (or rows) as the determinant,

```
matrix_1 = ones(16,3);
matrix_2 = ones(14,3);
matrix_3 = ones(2,3);
matrix_4 = ones(10,3);
my_array = {matrix_1; matrix_2; matrix_3; matrix_4};

for ii = 1:length(my_array)-1
    current_mat = my_array{ii};
    compare_mat = my_array{ii+1};
    for xx = 1:size(current_mat,2)  % length of columns
        xx_info = current_mat(:,xx);  % Can compare across columns, since no of columns are consistent across multiple matrices
    end
end
```

Comment: It is not correct to say the OP used 'length of rows as opposed to ... columns'. As I pointed out `length` returns the length of the longest dimension, not number of  rows/columns.

Comment: ok. fair enough. I'll delete my answer since you've covered both. Thought i'd let you know before i delete it.